# How to Copy the Matching Columns between CSV Files Using Pandas?

Tags: python, csv, pandas, inner-join

I have two dataframes(f1_df and f2_df):

f1_df looks like:

```
ID,Name,Gender
1,Smith,M
2,John,M
```

f2_df looks like:

```
name,gender,city,id
```

**Problem:**

I want the code to compare the header of f1_df with f2_df by itself and copy the data of the matching columns using panda.

**Output:**

the output should be like this:

```
name,gender,city,id  # name,gender,and id are the only matching columns btw   f1_df and f2_df 
Smith,M, ,1          # the data copied for name, gender, and id columns 
John,M, ,2
```

I am new to Pandas and not sure how to handle the problem.  I have tried to do an inner join to the matching columns, but that did not work.

Here is what I have so far:

```
import pandas as pd

f1_df = pd.read_csv("file1.csv")
f2_df = pd.read_csv("file2.csv")

for i in f1_df:
    for j in f2_df:
        i = i.lower()
        if i == j:
            joined = f1_df.join(f2_df)
print joined
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this if you want to merge / join your DFs on common columns:

first lets convert all columns to lower case:

```
df1.columns = df1.columns.str.lower()
df2.columns = df2.columns.str.lower()
```

now we can join on common columns

```
common_cols = df2.columns.intersection(df1.columns).tolist()
joined = df1.set_index(common_cols).join(df2.set_index(common_cols)).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
In [259]: joined
Out[259]:
   id   name gender city
0   1  Smith      M  NaN
1   2   John      M  NaN
```

export to CSV:

```
In [262]: joined.to_csv('c:/temp/joined.csv', index=False)
```

c:/temp/joined.csv:

```
id,name,gender,city
1,Smith,M,
2,John,M,
```

Comment: What if I want the program to recognize the matching columns by it self and then copy that data of those matching column names.

Comment: @MEhsan, do you want to match columns, ignoring their case - case-insensitive?

Comment: Yes, the program should find the matching columns even if they are upper-case.